# Comparing values in arrays php

Tags: php, arrays, session, for-loop

I am making a simple game that generate array of 4 elements, and store it values in session, and then, through form users submits their guess, after php need to compare values from both array.

What is the problem.
Well, in my script, PHP simply doesn't compare their first [0] index, so loop cannot execute right result.

If someone would be gentle to tell me what problem is here, because i am stuck for days..

When user clicks on submit button in the form, it is submitted in session array called user_combo

```
$usercombocount=count($user_combo);
```

> 1.check is, is user inputed values have same value like generated
>   array,
>
> 2nd is, if not check does that value is in array

So, it simply skips what user has inputed first.. Don't have a clue how to fix this..

Edit:Here is full code:

```
$diamond = 'diamond';
        $heart = 'heart';
        $spade = 'spade';
        $club = 'club';
        $star='star';
        $qmark='qmark';

        $time=microtime(35);
        $arr=[$diamond,$heart,$spade,$club,$star,$qmark];   //Array of cards
        $niz=array();
        $msg=array();
    /* Fisher Yates for randomising*/
        function fisherYatesShuffle(&$items, $time){    
                for ($i = count($items) - 1; $i > 0; $i--){
                    $j = @mt_rand(0, $i);
                    $tmp = $items[$i];
                    $items[$i] = $items[$j];
                    $items[$j] = $tmp;
                }
                return $items;
            }



        if (isset($_POST['generate'])) {

            $i=0;

            do {
            $niz[$i]=fisherYatesShuffle($arr,$time);
            $i++;
            }
            while ($i <= 3);

            foreach ($niz as $key ) {
                    $randomArr[]=$key[0];

                }
            $_SESSION['final_kombo']=$randomArr;    // We are inserting our generated combination in $_SESSION['final_combo']
            $_SESSION['user_combo'];

        }

if (isset($_POST['spade'])) {
        $pik=$_POST['spade'];
        }
    if (isset($_POST['diamond'])) {
            $karo = $_POST['diamond'];
        }
    if (isset($_POST['club'])) {
            $tref=$_POST['club'];
        }
    if (isset($_POST['star'])) {
            $zvezda=$_POST['star'];
        }
    if (isset($_POST['heart'])) {
            $srce=$_POST['heart'];
        }
    if (isset($_POST['qmark'])) {
            $random =$_POST['qmark'];
        }

$user_combo=$_SESSION['user_combo'];
    $final_kombo=$_SESSION['final_kombo'];

if (isset($pik)) {
        $_SESSION['user_combo'][].=$pik;
    }

    if (isset($karo)) {
        $_SESSION['user_combo'][].=$karo;
    }
    if (isset($tref)) {
        $_SESSION['user_combo'][].=$tref;
    }
    if (isset($zvezda)) {
        $_SESSION['user_combo'][].=$zvezda;
    }
    if (isset($srce)) {
        $_SESSION['user_combo'][].=$srce;
    }
    if (isset($random)) {
        $_SESSION['user_combo'][].=$random;
    }

for ($i=0; $i < 3 ; $i++) { 
            echo "I JE :  ".$i . " <br>";
            //echo $user_combo[$i]. "<br>";
            if (($_SESSION['user_combo'][$i] === $_SESSION['final_kombo'][$i])) {

                //echo "I je : ".$i . " </ br>";
                $msg[]="Index are same </br>";
            }
            if(in_array($_SESSION['user_combo'][$i],$_SESSION['final_kombo'])) {
                $msg[]="It is in final kombo <br>";
            }
        }

//foreach is just for develop purposes, it simply echoes output of msg[]

foreach ($msg as $key) {
            echo "<b>".$key."</b>";

        }
```

And html:

```
            <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST" id="form">



<input type="submit" name="generate" value="Start the game!"><br>

    <input type="submit" name="spade" value="spade" class="spade">
    <input type="submit" name="diamond" value="diamond" class="diamond">
            <input type="submit" name="club" value="club" class="club">
            <input type="submit" name="heart" value="heart" class="heart">

            <input type="submit" name="qmark" value="qmark" class="qmark">
    <input type="submit" name="star" value="star" class="star"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="reset" value="Reset">

        </form>
```

And thats all. I know my code need deep refactoring, I will do it when everything works correctly :) I hope I am clearer now, thank you all for help :)

Comment: what value do you have in $user_combo and $final_kombo.

Comment: Also provide your expected output?

Comment: after if add print_r($user_combo); to debug

Comment: It is card game. Generated array contains random 4 elements of 6 available cards. I have club, diamond, heart, star, random(just name of element), spade. So when user clicks on 'generate btn', i get 4 random elements stored in session.
After than, when user click on for ex. 'club', it gets stored in session array, and when there are max 4 tries, i want to compare those indexes and values.

Comment: Shouldn't you `count($_SESSION['user_combo'])` instead of `count($user_combo)`? Or do you initialize `$user_combo` somewhere? Please add the code where you assign values to your variables (like syed mohamed suggested earlier).

Comment: Yes yes, those are vars
$user_combo=$_SESSION['user_combo'];
$final_kombo=$_SESSION['final_kombo'];
($final_kombo has random generated array in my function)

Comment: Please add all the code you are using into your question. It's difficult to keep track what is happening since you leave things out and add some code into to the comments. (It's okay to minimize but you should explain what you've left out so we don't have to guess where does the variables come from.)

Comment: Does the $user_combo really hold all the values? You are checking with ===. Would == check work? Do you take into account case-sensitivity?